# Non equal width of button inside LinearLayout inside RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Can't understand, why buttons are not identical in their sizes. Earlier, I used LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout as a root, but after some googling I understand, there is no chance to make footer with LL, so I make it RL and adjusted by coping previous LL with buttons to RL, but.. [Look at this. I found it with ruler. It really cut my eyes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qysF5.png)

Also I can't understand, why margin in RL doesn't work anyway (I deleted in from below code), and how I can margin elements inside RL?!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/all_mentions_Add" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/all_mentions_Delete" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_mentions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/linearLayout_buttons" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

instead of

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

in your Buttons, for weights to work (trick!)

Also set `android:orientation="horizontal"` in your LinearLayout

Comment: I tried to set margin inside RL. It doesn't make child to margin. LL makes, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can make footer with LL:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_mentions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/all_mentions_Add" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/all_mentions_Delete" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also change width of buttons to `match_parent` if You want to make width of buttons identically.

Comment: what's going on with LL, when one element have weight and another haven't? Is it mean "element without weight will fill all of space without other elements"?

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_mentions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_add"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/all_mentions_Add" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_delete"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/all_mentions_Delete" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How does 0dp help me? O_o And why pure weight=1 didn't do that?